# Getting "Symbol's function definition is void: nil" when adding or following up in GNUS

Tags: gnus

Emacs 24.5 (from http://emacsformacosx.com), GNUS 5.13, OS X El Capitan.

When I try to post to a newsgroup or followup an existing post, I get the error "Symbol's function definition is void: nil" from GNUS.  Viewing works fine.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: No, but try doing M-x toggle-debug-on-error before, then you will get a backtrace, which hopefully can shed some light on where the problem arises.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did that but got no backtrace, just the same error message.

Comment: Okay, that was weird.  I commented out my flyspell config that I picked up from somewhere and the problem went away.  That'll teach me some elisp hygiene.

Answer (score -1):

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (flyspell-mode 1))
(dolist (hook '(change-log-mode-hook log-edit-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode -1))))
```

was the culprit.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (flyspell-mode 1))` is probably to blame. `add-hook` adds a *function* to a list, and `(flyspell-mode 1)` does not evaluate to a function.